# Flask: How to route between html templates and display results from sqlite db?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I''m new to Flask and trying to add routing from `home.html` to  `results.html` and display results in html instead of raw json.

With the below code I'm able to connect to my .db and query it, for example:
To filter entries based on post id : 127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/jobs/datascience?Business=ACME

`api.py`:

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify
import sqlite3
import numpy as np 

# Debug allows for changes to be seen in real time.
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

def dictFactory(cursor, row):
    """
    Function that parses the entries of the database and returns them as a list of dictionaries.

    @param cursor -- A cursor object using sqlite.
    @param row -- The row of the database being parsed.
    """
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def homePage():
    return '''
    <h1>Datascience Jobs Database</h1> 
    <h3>You have reached: /home/</h3>
    <p>To view all entries in the database: '127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/jobs/datascience/all' </p>
    <p>To filter entries based on country : '127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/jobs/datascience?country=United%20States' </p>
    <p>To filter entries based on post id : '127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/jobs/datascience?id=81953194' </p>
'''

@app.route('/api/v1/jobs/datascience/all', methods=['GET'])
def apiViewAll():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data/datasciencejobs_database.db')
    conn.row_factory = dictFactory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    all_books = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tblJobs;').fetchall()

    return jsonify(all_books)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def pageNotFound(e):
    return "<h1>Error 404</h1><p>Page not found.</p>", 404

@app.route('/api/v1/jobs/datascience', methods=['GET'])
def apiViewByFilter():
    '''
    Function that allows users to filter the results in the API based on specified input.
    '''
    query_parameters = request.args

    id = query_parameters.get('BusinessID')
    dateTime = query_parameters.get('date')
    cleanContent = query_parameters.get('Business')
    country = query_parameters.get('country')

    query = "SELECT * FROM tblJobs WHERE"
    to_filter = []

    if id:
        query += ' BusinessID=? AND'
        to_filter.append(id)

    if dateTime:
        query += ' date=? AND'
        to_filter.append(dateTime)

    if cleanContent:
        query += ' Business=? AND'
        to_filter.append(cleanContent)

    if country:
        query += ' country=? AND'
        to_filter.append(country)

    if not (id or dateTime or cleanContent or country):
        return pageNotFound(404)

    query = query[:-4] + ';'

    conn = sqlite3.connect('data/datasciencejobs_database.db')
    conn.row_factory = dictFactory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()

    return jsonify(results)

app.run()
```

I think the next step would be to add into `api.py` something like:

```
from flask import request, jsonify, Flask, render_template

@app.route('/')
def main_searchPage():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

`home.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/home.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="searchText">Search:</h2>
<form class="searchText" id="searchForm" action="{{ url_for('main_searchPage') }}" method="get">
Business Name: <input class="searchText" id="searchInput" type="text" name="Business"><br>
    <input class="searchText" id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above html page includes one form field to search by 'Business' and after submitting the form with value 'ACME' I’m trying to get result as for 127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/jobs/datascience?Business=ACME but instead of raw json it should Display on `results.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Results Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/results.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="myResults">
    <h3>Your Business {{ Business }}</h3>
    <h2>BusinessID {{ BusinessID }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ date }}</h3>
    <h4>Business Located in: : {{ country }}</h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would someone be able to help me with the above or at least give some pointers regarding what should I change in the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- replace `return jsonify(results)` with `return render_template('results.html', results=results)`
- Then in `results.html` change your div to something like this:

```
<div id="myResults">
    <h3>Your Business {{ results.Business }}</h3>
    <h2>BusinessID {{ results.BusinessID }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ results.date }}</h3>
    <h4>Business Located in: : {{ results.country }}</h4>
</div>
```

This template part might need some debugging depending in what `results` looks like but that's how you pass data from flask to the template.